# Passing special characters as Query parameters in a Spring RESTful application

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I want to pass **" & ; \n ?**  etc as characters in my query parameter. But since they have special meaning in HTTP protocol , i feel i need to somehow 'escape' these characters to disable their functionality.

How can i do that if i want to pass them as a normal string sequence in a RESTful Spring boot application query parameter ?

I was able to replace the \n with the %0A as some answers on here suggested , but i guess i need to do some more fixes. Here is my string :-

"package drl; %0A import com.example.demo.Apple; %0A dialect 'mvel' %0A rule Apple_is_green_yall %0A when %0A $person : Apple(color == \"Green\") %0A then %0A System.out.println(\"Appl green yo guys \") %0A end"

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data should be URL Encoded. You can use `java.net.URLEncoder` to replace all special characters with the appropriate `%XY` representation.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

Like this:

```java
import java.net.URLEncoder
[...]
String input = "#your $data %here"
// You can use other charsets but UTF-8 is recommended
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This example will take the string "#your $data %here" and output "%23your%20%24data%20%25here".

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out !

Comment: Java URL encoder would encode spaces as '+'.
So, you will be getting '%23your+%24data+%25here' as the response.

Also URLEncoder accepts a string as the second argument. So, you will have to use something like 
String encodedText = URLEncoder.encode(text,String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));